# Selecting an area with exception of merged cells in dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

---

**IMPORTANT EDIT:** The main issue here is caused by **hidden merged cells that are causing the entirity of their active range to be selected.** Unless you know a way how to dynamically skip merged cells (in a dynamic range), the it most likely won't help. Have changed the entirity of question accordingly

---

any idea what am I doing wrong?

Got the following code, fyi  the function `find_last_row` returns the value of last active row as integer. In this case, the returned variable would be 40

```
Private Sub initalize_button_Click()

    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Training_Planner")


    lastRow = find_last_row

    With ws
        .Activate
        .Range("E5:H" & lastRow).Select
    End With


End Sub
```

Pretty basic code, should open the worksheet Training_Planner and select from E5 to HlastRow **(in this case lastRow is 40)** so the selected range should be E5:H40

Here is the expected result:

[image]

What I get instead:

[image]

**Curiously enough, it selects only active range, but it's as if it didn't pay attention to columns, instead of the expected E5:H40 i get B5:I40
Any idea what's causing this?**

Comment: Do you have any merged cells in that range?

Comment: @ScottCraner yes, that would be the cells in Column B. But they should not be part of my Selection that would start from E5

Comment: Probably you have a hidden row, which is merged from `B` to `I`, thus it is happenning this way.

Comment: @Vityata yeah that would be the case. Is there a way to somehow ignore the merged cells without having to remove them?

Comment: @Rawrplus - if you want to select the range with the hidden merged cells - then no.

Comment: You can always unmerge first then select.

Comment: You said your range is dinamic. Just wondering... 100% dinamic?? or just E5:another cell?  or onecell:anothercell? I just want to know if, even dynamic, maybe some part of your range is going to be always the same. Your Range is (Cells(a,b),Cells(c,d)). Are a,b,c and d dymanic the 4 of them?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Fully dynamic. E5:FirstDynamicValue, DynamicValue2:DynamicValue3 etc etc. Only E5 is stable.  So in the example you provided, a would be static, rest dynamic. to put it simply, I'm working with ever expanding and reducing pool of data. I coded a vba Inputbox where you have to manually enter the range of each part. Not the most elegant solution, but at least it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first of all, if your range is gonna start always as E5, your range is 50% dinamic, because it starts always in same column and same row. Your Range is (Cells(a,b),Cells(c,d)), this means a = 5 and b = 5 (Column E).

Also, you say and Inputbox asks users for end cell of range (in your example is H40, but this is dynamic).

So, my code checks EVERY SINGLE cell in the range formed, and then, using `Application.Union`I set a *final big range*. We cannot just use an array to select all of them, because your range is dynamic, and selecting ranges with arrays is limited to 30 args, so we need to update our FinalRange for each cell.

```
Dim MyCell As Range
Dim RangeWanted As Range
Dim MyFinalRange As Range

Set RangeWanted = Range("E5:" & InputBox("Cell Address")) 'User inputs Final Cell of Range. Start is always E5


'let's get all invididual addresses of each cell inthat dynamic RangeWanted
For Each MyCell In RangeWanted

    If MyCell.MergeCells = False Then 'If not merged, we add it to FinalRange

        If MyFinalRange Is Nothing Then
            Set MyFinalRange = MyCell
        Else
            Set MyFinalRange = Application.Union(MyFinalRange, MyCell)
        End If

    End If
Next MyCell

Set RangeWanted = Nothing

MyFinalRange.Select
```

With this code, from Range("E5:H40") in image,yellow cells are merged. I want to select only the not merged ones. And using this code, I get this:

[image]

My example is with Range("E5:H40") but it works also with other ranges.

Try it and adapt the code to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever something small like this is happening, simply try to simplify as much as you can. In your case, it would be this:

```
Sub TestMe()
    Worksheets("Training_Planner").Range("E5:H40").Select
End Sub
```

If it selects `E5:H40` then everything is ok. If not, try to select it manually. Probably you have a hidden row, which is merged from B to I, thus it is happenning this way.

Comment: Yeah, the issue is being caused by hidden rows. Issue  is, I'm working with a dynamic range, so I can't even split it into multiple ranges...I guess this will have to be changed by manual user input. Thanks for the help anyways

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:
`.Range("E5:H" & lastRow).Select`

Try going with this: 
`.Range("E5", (Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp))).Select`

It count all the rows "H" has and then goes up until it finds the first item. And it will then select from "E1" to last item in "H"